# Django ManytoMany filter exact list

Tags: django, django-models

Suppose I have a list of id's: c = ['1', '2' , '3']

```
class Topic(Model):

 categories=ManyToManyField(Category)
```

How can I filter topics that have exact and only categories with id's from c?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to call `.filter(categories=category_id)` for each element in the `c` list.

```
c = [1, 2, 3]
topics = reduce(lambda qs, pk: qs.filter(categories=pk), c, Topic.objects.all())
```

And then if you want to exclude topics with additional categories (e.g. a topic with `[1,2,3,4]`), then you need to `.annotate` and `.filter` on the total count.

```
c = [1, 2, 3]
initial_qs = Topic.objects.annotate(cnt=models.Count('categories')).filter(cnt=len(c))
topics = reduce(lambda qs, pk: qs.filter(categories=pk), c, initial_qs)
```

Comment: This is Django wizardry. Thanks!