# Django ManytoMany filter exact list with duplicate items

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is extension for the question [Django ManytoMany filter exact list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40505500/django-manytomany-filter-exact-list)

Looks like accepted answer doesn't work when list contains duplicates.
Is there any solution?

Basically, I split sentence into tokens and want to search by that tokens.

```
class Sentence(Model):
    name = CharField()

class Tokens(Model):
   token = CharField()
   sentence = ForeignKey(Sentence, related_name='tokens')
```

Suppose, I have the tokens `['che', 'farebbe', 'dalle', 'dalle']`. I want to find sentences that consist exactly of these tokens.

```
Sentence.objects.annotate(n=Count('tokens')).filter(tokens__name='che').filter(tokens__name='farebbe').filter(tokens__name='dalle').filter(n=4)
```

doesn't work. `n` is more than `4` (I guess, because of joins).

If list of tokens doesn't have duplicates then everything is working fine.

Comment: Try using the `tokens__name__in` chaining the filter just seem redundant.

Comment: Without chaining it will give empty queryset.

Comment: So this doesn't work `Sentence.objects.annotate(n=Count('tokens', distinct=True)).filter(tokens__name__in=['che', 'farebbe', 'dalle'], n=4)`

Comment: This works, but not as expected. This will give sentences where at least one token occurs.

Comment: Try `.filter(Q(tokens__name='che') & Q(tokens__name='farebbe') )`

Comment: Empty queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: add `distinct=True` to `Count`:

```
Sentence.objects.annotate(n=Count('tokens', distinct=True)).filter(tokens__name='che').filter(tokens__name='farebbe').filter(tokens__name='dalle').filter(n=4)
```